# How to create a new dataset based on multiple conditions in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset

I have a dataset called `carcom` that looks like this

```
carcom <- data.frame(household = c(173, 256, 256, 319, 319, 319, 422, 422, 422, 422), individuals= c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4))
```

Where individuals refer to father for "1" , mother for "2", child for "3" and "4". What I would like to get two new columns. First one should indicate the number of children in that household if there is. Second, assigning a weight to each individual respectively "1" for father, "0.5" to mother and "0.3" to each child. My new dataset should look like this

```
newcarcom <- data.frame(household = c(173, 256, 319, 422), child = c(0, 0, 1, 2), weight = c(1, 1.5, 1.8, 2.1)
```

I have been trying to find the solutions for days. Would be appreciated if someone helps me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can count number of `individuals` with value 3 and 4 in each `household`. To calculate `weight` we change the value for 1:4 to their corresponding weight values using `recode` and then take `sum`.

```
library(dplyr)

newcarcom <- carcom %>%
  group_by(household) %>%
  summarise(child = sum(individuals %in% 3:4), 
            weight = sum(recode(individuals,`1` = 1, `2` = 0.5, .default = 0.3)))

#  household child weight
#      <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
#1       173     0    1  
#2       256     0    1.5
#3       319     1    1.8
#4       422     2    2.1
```

---

Base R version suggested by @markus

```
newcarcom <- do.call(data.frame, aggregate(individuals ~ household, carcom, function(x) 
      c(child = sum(x %in% 3:4), weight = sum(replace(y <- x^-1, y < 0.5, 0.3)))))
```

Comment: Maybe add this base R option too: `aggregate(individuals ~ household, carcom, function(x) c(child = sum(x %in% 3:4), weight = sum(replace(y <- x^-1, y < 0.5, 0.3))))`

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. However I have a small problem. When I run the code I can have the output for both "child" and "weight" in console page, but when I try to convert it to a dataset I have just the output for "child". Do you have any idea?

Comment: @BaranAksoy `dplyr` returns a dataframe as required. `newcarcom <- carcom %>%
  group_by(household).....`. For `aggregate` if you store data in `newcarcom` like `newcarcom  <- aggregate(individuals ~ household, carcom,.....` you can then do `newcarcom <- do.call(data.frame, newcarcom)` to get data as separate columns. See updated answer.

Comment: It is obvious that I am a beginner. Thanks again @markus

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(carcom)[, .(child = sum(individuals %in% 3:4), 
        weight = sum(recode(individuals,`1` = 1, `2` = 0.5, .default = 0.3))), household]
```